# Dirac Delta Measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about the Dirac delta measure. Does the "sifting" property hold at the limits of integration? That is, does $\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\delta_b(dx)=f(b)$?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as you're sure to include the endpoint $b$. The Dirac delta measure at $b$ is defined by

$$\delta_b (A) = \chi_A (b) := \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } b \in A \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

The integral of $f$ over the region $[a,b]$ is just the integral of $f \chi_{[a,b]}$; so we are interested in the measure $\chi_{[a,b]}\delta_b$:
$$
\chi_{[a,b]}\delta_b (A) = \int \chi_A \chi_{[a,b]}\delta_b 
= \int \chi_{A \cap [a,b]}\delta_b 
= \delta_b(A \cap [a,b])=\delta_b(A)
$$
since $b\in[a,b]$ implies $b \in A \cap [a,b] \iff b \in A$. 
Thus we have

$$\int_{[a,b]} f \delta_b = \int f \chi_{[a,b]} \delta_b = \int f \delta_b = f(b).$$
This reflects the fact that from the point of view of measure theory and Lebesgue integration, the endpoint isn't special in any way - we can define the Dirac delta measure for any point of any measure space.

Comment: I thought it picked up the average of the discontinuity? Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Cameron: You're probably thinking of a very different framework for defining integral operators.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: As Hurkyl mentioned, you need to be careful about the objects you're using when looking at edge cases like this - if you approximate $\delta$ by even "peak" functions $\phi_n$, then $\int f \phi_n$ does indeed converge to the average value across the discontinuity; but $\phi_n \to \delta$ only as distributions (not measures) and we can't act on a discontinuous function with a distribution! Thus we cannot conclude that $\int f \delta$ = $\lim \int f \phi_n$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks for correcting me!